# Injector error - $routeParams with AngularUI router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-router

Went from using ngRoute to ui.Router ($stateProvider instead of $routeProvider) so I am not sure if I am refactoring correctly.. Trying to access an object detail using the $routeParams to get the ID.   I am using ui-sref to get the ID client side, but am not sure how to render data with $http.

This is how I am getting the params:

```
<h4 class="inline-header">Topic Name:</h4>
   <span> <a ui-sref="listing-detail({listingId:listing._id})">{{listing.topic}}</a></span>
```

from my controller..

```
   angular
  .module('identifly', [
    'ui.router',
    'satellizer'
  ])

configRoutes.$inject = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", 
"$locationProvider"]; // minification protection
function configRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, 
$locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('listing-detail', {
     url: '/listing/:listingId',
     templateUrl: 'templates/listing-show.html',
     controller: 'ListingShowController',
     controllerAs: 'listingShowCtrl'
    });
```

Hitting this controller...

```
ListingShowController.$inject = ['$http', '$routeParams'];
function ListingShowController ($http, $routeParams) {
 var vm = this;

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/listings/'+$routeParams.id
  }).then(function successCallback(json) {
    vm.listing = json.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('There was an error getting the data', response);
  });

};
```

And getting this error:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20$routeParams%20%3C-%20ListingShowController

Comment: you need inject ui.router and use `$stateParams` insteed `routeParams`

Comment: I edited the post to include my entire controller. Do I need to inject it again in my Show controller?

Comment: in show controller , you need inject $stateParams , and change your url to      `url: '/api/listings/'+$stateParams.listingId`